# Lat Lon through HTTP POST

Tags: ios, string, http-post, core-location

Ok, so my iOS app requires sending Latitude & Longitude to recieve the suburb through a `HTTP POST` method.

This is my code for getting the Lat & Lon

```
float lat = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float lon = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
```

I want to send this in a HTTP POST method like this

```
here is the problem
NSString *post = @"key1=val1&key2=val2";
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nowhere.com/sendFormHere.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

What I want to know is if I can change the `float` part in to a string or something similar to use in the `HTTP POST` method

Comment: So the question is really how do i convert float to string?  That's been answered on SO before.  BTW, latitide and longitude fields in coordinate are type `CLLocationDegrees` which is double, not float.  float does not have enough precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the post:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat=%f&lon=%f", lat, lon];
```

Comment: Ok, lets say now, I have a list of suburbs like this; 
`<state name="ACT">
<suburb name="Acton" id="2715" latitude="-35.2773337" longitude="149.1182098"></suburb>
<suburb name="Ainslie" id="2712" latitude="-35.2626801" longitude="149.1448231"></suburb></state>` How do I get something to display what Suburb my Lat Lon says I'm in?

Comment: Better off actually, how do I display the results of `POST` In the form of a String if it comes back like `<geocode>
<suburb>Acton</suburb>
<state>ACT</state>
</geocode>`

Comment: That is messy xml to parse, if you have any control of the format use an array of dictionaries.

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Create a data model and methods in the data model to parse the xml and populate ivars. Add methods to provide the data in whatever format is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can add the float in the body:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lat=%f,long%f",lat,lon];
```